# How to wrap words earlier to justify text up to the last line?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a short text that I need to be centered, and justified as much as possible. However, if the text is only slightly longer than the div, only one or two words wrap around, where I would like to have words wrapping earlier so that the last line has approximately the same width as the previous ones.

Here's the code I use (CSS inlined for brevity):

```html
<div style="width: 250px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; box-sizing: border-box;">
    This text is long enough that a word wraps.
</div>
<div style="width: 250px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0 40px;">
    This text is long enough that a word wraps.
</div>
```

Here's an example of what happens:

[image: screenshot of two divs]

The second div is what I would like to see, however I can't adjust the padding manually because the text is of variable width.

I'm not sure a pure CSS solution exists, but I hope there's one :) I'm using Firefox (latest) if that's relevant.

Comment: There is no CSS method. You require javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you can nest some element inside `div`, than you can set the width for that element:

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  width: calc(100% - 30px); /*In addition, you can use percents `width: 30%`*/
  text-align: end;
}
```

```html
 <div>
    <p>
      This text is long enough that a word wraps.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      This text is long enough that a word wraps.
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: This works, but I have dynamic text so I can't set an exact width for the sub-element. Ideally, in my example I'd have to set `p { width: 170px; }` but I can't know that value beforehand.

Comment: @Zeroji try to use `calc` method to calculate width of  `p`. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, but the behavior I want would be to have the end of the 2nd line aligned with the end of the 1st line (as much as possible), like this:

`This text is long enough`
`that a word wraps.`

Comment: @Zeroji I've updated my answer. `text-align: end;` is added. Could you see whether it is eligible for you

Comment: thanks for your efforts but that's not the effect I want, I would like all lines to be of the same width. However, even if I add `<wbr>` into the text manually, it doesn't break on it and only breaks later. I think I'll have to go with automatically inserting `<br>` tags :(